# Parent Child Perl Data Structure

Tags: perl, data-structures, directed-graph

I have a datafile that has a list of paired values representing river flow relationships.

The file has this structure

```
Node       Downstream Node
A          B
B          C
C          D
E          C

etc
```

What I need to do is read this file and then for any given node, I need all the UPSTREAM nodes printed.

In the example above if I entered C, I would get E, B, A.

I am using perl on a linux box and the person I am writing this for is too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The correct data structure for your problem is a [Graph](http://metacpan.org/module/Graph):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;
use Graph::Directed;

my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my ($v1, $v2) = split ' ', $line;
    $g->add_edge($v1, $v2);
}

print $g->all_predecessors('D'), "\n";

__DATA__
A          B
B          C
C          D
E          C
```

```
C:\Temp> h
ACEB
```

Comment: Wow, thats a powerful tool. Just for point of comparison I ran for `print $g->all_predecessors('C'), "\n";` and indeed got `AEB`

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?  This seems to work, assuming we can load the entire thing into memory.  I also assumed each line only had one upstream value and one downstream value. Allowing more is left as an excersise for the reader.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;

my %links;
while(<DATA>)
{
    my ($key, $val) = split ' ', $_;
    $links{$key}{down}{$val} = 1; # dupes not allowed/ignored
    $links{$val}{up}{$key}   = 1;
}

sub gather_up
{
    my $start = shift;
    my $seen  = shift || {};

    my @up;
    if ($links{$start}{up})
    {
        for my $u (sort keys %{$links{$start}{up}})
        {
            unless ($seen->{$u}++)
            {
                push @up, $u;
            }
        }

        push @up, map { gather_up($_, $seen) } @up;
    }

    @up
}

say join ', ', gather_up('C');

__END__
A          B
B          C
C          D
E          C
```